# calling the ibaction method programmatically is not changing the background of the button?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

I had an application in which I am adding some dynamic number of buttons to a scrollview. I had set a normal background and selected background for the `UIButton`. For some reasons I need to call the `UIButton` sender method programmatically by:

```
[self buttontapped:nil];
```

as this but it is not changing the background of the button by using the code:

```
button.selected = YES;
```

I had set the background like this initially of the button:

```
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    int j = i+1;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake((j-1)*77, 0, 77, 44);
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_hvr.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    btn.selected = NO;
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    btn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [btn setTitle:head forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag = i;
    [tabBarS addSubview:btn];

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(sender==nil)
    {
        btn.tag=0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<[sarray count];i++)
    {
           btn.selected=NO;  
     }
    btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"Tab bar %d is clicked",btn.tag);
    [self tabCall:btn.tag];
    btn.selected = YES; 
}
```

But everything except change of background only working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: sender value not coming properly i think so.

Comment: i suspect that btn hold other button's instance not the desired one. try to debug it.

Comment: Change IBAction Instead of -(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender.

Comment: Check state of Button after setSelect if(btn.selected)

Comment: Where do you set the background? is `btn` already created and connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i done with bellow method call your UIButton method like:-

```
btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    int j=i+1;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake((j-1)*77, 0, 77, 44);
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_hvr.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    btn.selected=NO;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    btn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    btn.tag = i;
    [tabBarS addSubview:btn];
```

and it's Action Method should like with sender

```
-(IBAction)yourButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    if (![btn isSelected])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_fb_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setSelected:YES];

        [self login];
    }
    else{
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setSelected:NO];

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

You can call button action event programeticuly using bellow trik:-

**[btn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];**

Comment: Instead of this `-(IBAction)yourButtonAction:(id)sender` we can assume like `-(IBAction)yourButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender` also right? No need to create one button locally :)

Comment: try to fine programeticuly button event [btn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

write this bellow line first and also change the method type from `void` to `IBAction`...

```
btn = (UIButton *)sender;
```

like bellow...

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(sender==nil)
    {
     btn.tag=0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<[sarray count];i++)
    {
       [btn setSelected:NO];
     }
    NSLog(@"Tab bar %d is clicked",btn.tag);
    [self tabCall:btn.tag];
    [btn setSelected:YES];
}
```

Comment: i need to do the selection process of the first button needs to done programatically?

Comment: is it due to the sender is nil?

Comment: @hacker see this link with custombutton code and use that code instead of yours http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/12/custom-button.html :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image property rather than `backgroundImage` property of `UIButton`.
Use `default` Image property and `selected` property.

```
[btn setSelected:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 0):

is the log that you are printing, prints the button.tag correctly?

NSLog(@"Tab bar %d is clicked",btn.tag);

Answer (score -1):

In your button action

```
   btn.selected=YES;
```

in last line makes the button in selected state always

also get the correct instance as

```
btn=(UIButton *)sender;
```

Comment: You only need to cast it to avoid compiler warnings. As long as `sender` responds to the `selected` method, this isn't the cause of the problem.